# merge two queries with different where and different grouping into 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Sorry, I asked this question just before and got some good answers but then I realised I made a mistake with the query in question, if I change the question in the original post that could make the answers invalid so I'm posting again with the right query this time, please forgive me, I hope this is acceptable.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(MeasureDate, col1, col2, type)

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2, 1
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 1

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2, 3
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 1
AND Col4 = 7000

SELECT SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) AS Percentage, MeasureDate, Type
FROM @Temp
GROUP BY MeasureDate, Type
```

I do two inserts into the temp table, 2nd insert with an extra WHERE but same columns same table, but different type, then I do SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) on the temp table to return the result I need per MeasureDate and type. Is there a way to merge all these inserts and selects into one statement so I don't use a temp table and do a single select from Table1? Or even if I still need the temp table, merge the selects into one select instead of two separate selects? Stored procedure works fine as it is, just looking for a way to shorten it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure can. I might start with combining the two queries from your inserts using `UNION ALL` (this variation of `UNION` will not remove duplicates), wrapped up in a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) from which you can perform your final query:

```
WITH MeasureData(MeasureDate, col1, col2, type) AS (
    SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2, 1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Col3 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2, 3
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Col3 = 1
    AND Col4 = 7000
)
SELECT SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) AS Percentage, MeasureDate, Type
FROM MeasureData
GROUP BY MeasureDate, Type
```

That's it, no more table variable or insert statements.

Comment: nit: since there clearly can't be any duplicates between the first two queries, `union` and `union all` will do produce the same result, although `union all` **should** be a tad faster.

Comment: @Cory That looks good, thanks. Do you find a SP like mine is easier to debug though? Because after each insert I can do a select * from @@temp and see what's inside the @@temp when I call exec SP. I find it bit hard to test/debug queries like yours when I'm developing although it's a superior way of running the query.

Comment: I think you have to find a middle ground between testability and performance (leaning towards performance). Usually I start with writing the fastest possible query and I don't touch it unless absolutely necessary for debugging purposes.

Comment: It dawned on me the union all is necessary because there CAN be duplicates which would get eliminated (they would just be duplicates within the respective tables already.)  The 4th column values (1,3) doesn't guarantee uniqueness within the table1 itself.

Answer (score 3):

No real need for a `UNION`, you can handle this with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) AS Percentage, MeasureDate, Type
FROM (
    SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2, case when Col4 = 7000 then 3 else 1 end type
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Col3 = 1
) t
GROUP BY MeasureDate, Type
```

---

Edit, as Gordon correctly points out, for `Type = 1`, this query wouldn't produce the same results.  Here's a variation on Gordon's good answer that might be easier to visually understand using a `CROSS JOIN` and `IF` logic:

```
SELECT T1.MeasureDate, 
  T.Type, 
  SUM(IF(T.Type=1,Col1,IF(T.Type=3 AND T1.Col4=7000,T1.Col1,0))) / 
  SUM(IF(T.Type=1,Col2,IF(T.Type=3 AND T1.Col4=7000,T1.Col2,0))) AS Percentage
FROM Table1 T1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 Type UNION SELECT 3) T
WHERE T1.Col3 = 1
GROUP BY T1.MeasureDate, T.Type
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc618/7)

Comment: This produces different results from the original query, because the values for `col3 = 1 and col4 = 7000` are *not* being double counted this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is double counting cases where `col3 = 1` and `col4 = 7000`.  Here is a method that takes this into account, without `union` on the overall table:

```
select t.type, SUM(t1.col1) / SUM(t1.col2) AS Percentage, t1.MeasureDate, t.Type
from table1 t1 join
     (select 1 as type union all
      select 3 as type
     ) t
     on t.type = 1 or t1.col4 = 7000
where t1.col3 = 1
group by measuredate, type;
```

Comment: +1 -- I didn't think that was what the OP was going for, but sure enough, you are correct.  Thanks for pointing it out.